# Time taken to send a message in Amazon's SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs

How long does it take to send a message with Amazon Simple Queue Service?

Also, I'd like to know how many messages will be sent in a minute in Amazon SQS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 2007, [at least one user got these results:](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=16001)

```
threads, msgsPerRead   
1        1             1.389207 sec/msg
100      1             1.3945675675675675 sec/msg
100      10            0.7433736040609137 sec/msg
1        100           0.6860626349892008 sec/msg
10       100           0.6747456021650879 sec/msg
10       10            0.645827935222672 sec/msg
```

Looks like 1.5 seconds per read is safe for planning, or 40 reads per minute.