# SQS sendMessage latency variation?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a simple Java Lambda Request Handler that does nothing but write to SQS (don't ask). This is a single method whose only purpose is to call `sendMessage`.

Most of the time `sendMessage` returns in less than 30ms, all good. Every once in awhile `sendMessage` shoots to 300ms plus.

Nothing shows-up in the SQS monitoring console, any suggestions on how to figure this out?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6094077, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14256723, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25092000, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46840264

Comment: and [more about SQS throughput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-throughput-horizontal-scaling-and-batching.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to AWS Support from the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#Features.2C_functionality.2C_and_interfaces)

> Q: What is the typical latency for Amazon SQS?
>
> Typical latencies for SendMessage, ReceiveMessage, and DeleteMessage API requests are in the tens or low hundreds of milliseconds.

They also recommend [SDK Latency Logging.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-logging.html#sdk-latency-logging)